# How to delete the selected items in a list in swt

Tags: java, list, swt

I have created a list and a pop up menu to delete the element? How can I delete the element from the popup menu delete.

```
final List list = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER);
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("b");
final Menu menu = new Menu(list);
list.setMenu(menu);
menu.addMenuListener(new MenuAdapter()
{
    public void menuShown(MenuEvent e)
    {
        int selected = list.getSelectionIndex();

        if(selected < 0 || selected >= list.getItemCount())
            return;

        MenuItem[] items = menu.getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            items[i].dispose();
        }
        MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        newItem.setText("Delete");
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not really have anything to do with 'e4' as this is a purely SWT way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `newItem.setText("Delete");` line add the code below(Its adds selection listener to item). Also mark variable **selected** as final.

```java
newItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                list.remove(selected);
            }
});
```